# Linux/Unix command to check when a file was renamed

Tags: linux, unix

Is there a specific Unix/Linux command that would show when a file was renamed? I have a file in a Linux box and want to know when the file got renamed. I tried `ls -ltr` but that command only shows the date when it was created and not when it was last modified.

Is there a specific Unix/Linux command to do this?

Comment: This is very easily morphed into a programming question: "How do you write a program on Unix / Linux to tell when a file changed? Are there any commands that already do this?" with a sub-question "Are the commands portable?"  This is important information for shell programming, and programming (including shell programming) is specifically on-topic for SO.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use

```
stat filename
```

Check `Access` when it was last read.

Check `Modify` when it was updated.

Check `Change` if it was renamed.

Plus other file info like blocks, inodes, etc.

Comment: The change time reports when the inode was changed.  A rename doesn't change the inode.

Comment: I was referring to the field `Change`. I never said anything about inodes changing after rename.

Comment: Yes; but your answer says 'Change if it was renamed'.  The 'change' time is the time when the inode was changed (permissions set; owner changed; or size modified).  The 'change time' on the file doesn't change if the file is renamed (within a file system).  Your answer has been accepted by someone who didn't understand that what you said happens doesn't answer the question they appeared to be asking...which leaves me puzzled about what they were really asking.  Oh well, c'est la vie.

Comment: Indeed; I would expect rename to change in the parent directory, but not the file itself.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I understand its a kludge. There is no foolproof way without monitoring via inotify. But for a freshly renamed file, the `Change` field does reflect it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `$ touch foobar; stat foobar` -> `Change: 2013-07-22 11:27:04.380732148 -0500`, `$ mv foobar foobar2; stat foobar2` -> `Change: 2013-07-22 11:27:10.188731974 -0500`.  This sounds exactly like what the OP wanted, and not what you describe.

Comment: @lzkata: Which FS type? Yes; see my updated answer, which notes that ext4 specifically does record the time when a file is renamed in the file inode's ctime field, but contrast with HFS on Mac OS X which specifically does not change the file's inode. Interestingly, the POSIX [`rename()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rename.html)
entry doesn't say anything about changing the file inode; it does state _'Upon successful completion, `rename()` shall mark for update the last data modification and last file status change timestamps of the parent directory of each file.'_

Comment: @Izkata Can confirm on macOS Big Sur 11.4 (APFS), renaming a file in Finder does indeed update the `Change` time without updating `Inode`, which is what I thought the OP was asking and was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 7):

The behaviour is going to depend on the file system type.  On classic Unix file systems (and, amongst others, the Mac OS X HFS file system in particular), the interesting thing about a file rename within a file system is that it does not affect the inode of the file at all; it only affects the directory (or directories) where the file was moved from/to.  So, within a single file system, the only timestamps that change for a rename are the modify time of the directory holding the file.  For example<sup>*</sup>:

```
$ fl -a -c -m -n xxx.pl
2013-07-17 16:17:17 2013-07-17 16:17:17 2013-07-17 16:17:17 xxx.pl
$ mv xxx.pl yyy.pl
$ fl -a -c -m -n yyy.pl
2013-07-17 16:17:17 2013-07-17 16:17:17 2013-07-17 16:17:17 yyy.pl
$
```

This means that on such file systems, you cannot tell when the file was renamed some time after the file was renamed.

<sup>* `fl` is a home-brew command; the invocation is equivalent to the Mac OS X `stat` invocation `stat -f '%Sa %Sm %Sc %N'`.  This is only marginally related to the GNU/Linux `stat` command.</sup>

On the other hand, empirical evidence shows that a Linux ext4 file system does record the name change with a change of the modification time of the inode itself.

```
$ stat -c '%x %y %z %n' test.dat
2013-07-19 10:31:31.803842672 -0700 2013-07-19 10:31:31.803842672 -0700 2013-07-19 10:31:31.803842672 -0700 test.dat
$ mv test.dat test.data
$ stat -c '%x %y %z %n' test.data
2013-07-19 10:31:31.803842672 -0700 2013-07-19 10:31:31.803842672 -0700 2013-07-22 09:11:49.074339525 -0700 test.data
$
```

So, what you can do depends on the O/S on which you are running and which file system type your file is on.

If you have the inotify service available and running, you could record the event that is the file rename, but if you don't record the event, there is no 'post mortem' way to know when the file was renamed.

The modify time on the directory is not a good indication of when a specific file was changed; it changes whenever any file is created, moved, deleted.  If there's only a single file in the directory, then the change time probably indicates when that file was created or renamed, but single file directories are the exception and not the rule.

Comment: (For posterity) This does not seem to still be the case on more recent APFS filesystems for macOS as renaming a file does indeed update the `Change` field of `stat` without changing the `Inode` field.

Comment: @Leo — Yes; I agree.  When I check the times after moving a file, both the change and access times of the file are modified on macOS 10.14.6 Mojave (work machine — permission not granted to update — routine gnashing of teeth).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `inotify` library ([man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html)) to be notified when something happens on a file.
It's likely that there are bindings to scripting languages.

Comment: thanks i can definitely do that...but what if a specific file got renamed already and want to know when was it renamed then, that's what i want to know...

Comment: @user2579439 You can't know about past renamed. You can know about a rename at time T. Log it, or handle it right now, but you won't be able to know about past renames. See Jonathan answer for more info.

Comment: inotify is also correct and not confusing i with L with many fonts.

Answer (score 1):

On AIX, you can use equivalent of "stat" -

> istat filename

You should be able to know the file's last updated, modified and accessed time  down to the seconds along with some more information.